# Intellij spring integration flow diagram

Tags: intellij-idea, spring-integration

In Intellij do we have a feature to generate a flow diagram for message/event processing in various spring integration channels?
Given a complex spring integration XML config file with various transformers, inbound, outbound channels and service-activators, is there a way to pictorially view the flow across all these channels?

Is there any tool for such diagram generation?
**Note: its not just spring beans diagrams but actual message flow using spring integration**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Intellij, open the spring integration xml file and right click choose **Diagrams->Show Diagram->Spring Integration**

Funny that I missed to note it on right click.

Comment: Is this available when using annotation-based configuration?

Comment: This requires "UML Support" plugin to be enabled.